# Is it possible to read some value and then use this value in an update?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

The environment is gremlin (cosmos, specifically).

I would like to migrate a value from Vertex A to Vertex B. The vertices are connected by an edge, e.g.

```
A (Name: 'x') -[connected]-> B
```

Is it possible to read the 'Name' property in A and write it to B in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

With Gremlin you can label a step and then refer back to it later in the traversal with `select()`:

```
gremlin> g.addV().property('name','someone').as('a').
......1>   addV().property('name','').as('b').
......2>   addE('connected').from('a').to('b').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().has('name','someone').as('a').
......1>   out('connected').
......2>   property('name',select('a').values('name')).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().valueMap(true)
==>[id:0,name:[someone],label:vertex]
==>[id:2,name:[someone],label:vertex]
```

Please consider reading about [traversal induced values](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#traversal-induced-values) for some additional examples.